# Get accesstoken from azure in web with openidconnect

Tags: c#, azure, openid-connect

I have a desktop app where I authenticate users via Azure via `AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync`.

With the result from this method I can get the access-token, send it to my WCF and in my WCF use `JwtSecurityToken` / `ConfigurationManager< OpenIdConnectConfiguration >` to validate the token.

I've implemented login via Azure in a web app now by configuring it with `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`. So in my web app I dont explicitly call a method that returns a token. Rather I jack this in in asp.net's flow.

But now I want to fetch the token in a method and send it for validation similiarly how I did in my desktop app. I cannot find any token that the `ConfigurationManager` accepts however. I've looked in the regular `HttpContext` and `Owincontext` but no info that I find there is useful. Is the `accesstoken` stored anywhere where I can fetch it? Or do I have to do another request to get an `accesstoken`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting access token as part of the response.

A simple way would be to look at the Authorization header. Look at code below -

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

Also, I don't know what you mean by send the token for validation.

If you're trying to validate the token manually, here's a sample that does exactly that -

[Manually validating a JWT access token in a web API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/)

In the sample, specifically look at the Global.asax.cs

```
string jwtToken = null;
AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader = request.Headers.Authorization;
if (authHeader != null)
{
    jwtToken = authHeader.Parameter;
}
if (jwtToken == null)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = this.BuildResponseErrorMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        return response;
}

    .........
    .........
    .........

JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    // We accept both the App Id URI and the AppId of this service application
        ValidAudiences = new[] { audience, clientId },

    // Supports both the Azure AD V1 and V2 endpoint
        ValidIssuers = new[] { issuer, $"{issuer}/v2.0" },
        IssuerSigningKeys = signingKeys
};

try
{
    // Validate token.
        SecurityToken validatedToken = new JwtSecurityToken();
        ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwtToken, validationParameters, out validatedToken);
```